# Can't show text in the UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a view-based app that just does one thing : show a array in a TableView, but it doesn't work and I don't know why. Here's the code.

```
.h

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{
    NSArray *array;
    IBOutlet UITableView *table;
}

.m

-(void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
    array = [array initWithObjects:@"iPad", @"iTV", nil];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [array count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Any ideas why the TableView doesn't show the text? Thank you people!

Comment: Where is the `arrayInit` method called?

Comment: Sorry it was at the viewDidLoad. I'm gonna edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array = [array initWithObjects:@"iPad", @"iTV", nil];
```

Should be

```
array = [NSArray initWithObjects:@"iPad", @"iTV", nil];
```

also make sure you call arrayInit as barley mentioned

edit:
Vince is right in pointing out it should either be

```
[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"iPad", @"iTV", nil];
```

or

```
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"iPad",@"iTV",nil];
```

depending on if you want to retain or have it auto released

Comment: shouldn't it be `[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:...];` or `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:...];` ?

Comment: yes you're right it should be arrayWithObjects... I missed that.

Comment: The way you did it doesn't look right.  Could you put a breakpoint on it and check the array after you initialize it in viewDidLoad?  Forget about your arrayInit method, initializing the array in viewDidLoad is fine. Just try [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"iPad",@"iTV",nil] in your viewDidLoad method and see if that helps.

Comment: It's ok now. array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"iPad", @"iTV", nil]; works fine. But anyway the TableView doesn't show the text!

Comment: put a breakpoint at - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath?  Is your view controller loading?

Comment: Yes, it is. Maybe is possible that the wrong thing is the UITableViewDelegate and the UITableViewDataSource. Have I got to make something with them?

Comment: Now it works! All I had to do is to connect the delegate and the datasource in the storyboard with the ViewContorller! I'm happy!

Answer (score 1):

Ill assume you are running under ARC

NSIndexPath doesn't have a "row" property try

```
NSInteger row = [indexPath indexAtPosition:1];
cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:row];
```

Comment: `NSIndexPath` has a `row` property when you link with `UIKit`.  *[NSIndexPath UIKit Additions Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007175-CH3-DontLinkElementID_2)*

Comment: Cool. Learn something new every day